# Relation of vector process to Heat Equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, vectors, heat-equation

The user Dinisaur conjectured that the following vector process could maybe be analyzed via a discrete version of the heat equation.
I am personally not aware of the heat equation and maybe someone here has a feeling how the result could look like.

Intuitively my process can be interpreted as follows. We have an $n$ node line graph and the temperature at time step $t$ can be interpreted for every inner node as the average over its two neighbors.
At the boundaries of the graph, we increase the temperature a little bit at every time step.

More formally:

I have n vectors $v_1(t), \dots, v_n(t)$.
Time is divided into discrete rounds. 
Initially, all vectors have length $\leq 1$.
The vectors at the next time step $t+1$ can be calculated as follows:

\begin{align*}
v_1(t+1) &= \frac{v_1(t)}{2\|v_1(t)\|} + \frac{1}{2}v_2(t)\\
v_i(t+1) &= \frac{1}{2}v_{i-1}(t) + \frac{1}{2}v_{i+1}(t) \\
v_n(t+1) &= \frac{1}{2}v_{n-1}(t) + \frac{v_n(t)}{2\|v_n(t)\|}\\
\end{align*}

It turns out that this procedure converges and in the end all vectors are the same. However, I cannot predict the vector to which the vectors converge.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I can partially explain why you can't predict the vector to which the procedure converges. If you consider this as a discrete dynamical system (very roughly speaking, something that takes $x$ as an input and produces output $\bar{x}$ by some formula $\bar{x} = F(x)$ with $F$ better be differentiable), for **any** unit vector $v$ your system has $p_v = (v_1, v_2 , \dots, v_n) = (v, v, \dots, v)$ as a fixed point: the point for which $p_v = F(p_v)$. There are points that arbitrarily close to each other on this set, hence none of them can be an attracting fixed point.

Comment: Do you think with you intuition that it is impossible to predict the limit vector or only very difficult?

Comment: Let me say that I think it's difficult at this moment, but I wouldn't say impossible. Interesting fact: if you write $(\bar{v}_1, \dots, \bar{v}_n) = f(v_1, \dots, v_n)$, where $f$ is your mapping, you can see that for any rotation $R \in O(n)$ holds $f(Rv_1, \dots, Rv_n ) = (R\bar{v}_1, \dots, R\bar{v}_n)$, i.e. $O(n)$ with action $R \colon (x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto (Rx_1, \dots, Rx_n)$ is a symmetry of this system. It might shed some light on this system, but I haven't found any interesting consequences of this yet.